# Temporarily disable all other windows vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a color picker and I want it so on button press it will disable everything but the program (like what snipping tool does, but not add grey to the screen).

So when I click somewhere, it can capture the color from mouse pointer, and re-enable all other programs. The reason why I want it to disable all other programs is so when you click to pick the color then it won't interfere with anything and change the color.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Take a screenshot. Display it full screen in a borderless form that you control.

Comment: haha, good idea. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can do it, as like GSerg said, get your client rect image, put to picture box, and then after you click any location, take anything you need, then hide again your picturebox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this sample, there are two form FrmDesktopDisplay and FrmCaller

```
Public Class FrmDesktopDisplay
    Public myResultStts As Boolean = False
    Public myResultValue As Integer = -1

    Private Sub FrmDesktopDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
        'Here your code, not just in click event, you must modify according to your need
        'And for example the result as follow:
        myResultStts = True
        myResultValue = 30
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub FrmDesktopDisplay_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
            'Here Just Hide, don't be closed or disposed, because you need the result
            Me.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub FrmDesktopDisplay_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'First you must hide this form, to take desktop image
        Me.Hide()

        'This to make borderless
        Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None

        Me.Refresh()
        Dim g As Graphics
        Dim bmp As Bitmap

        'This to take size of screen
        Dim myWidth As Integer = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Size.Width
        Dim myHeight As Integer = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Size.Height

        'This to make this form's Size is same as screen size
        Me.Width = myWidth
        Me.Height = myHeight

        'Create Blank Bitmap with size as same as screen size
        bmp = New Bitmap(myWidth, myHeight)

        'Create graphic with composition of bitmap
        g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

        'Take Image from screen, and move to graphic g
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size)

        'Relocate this form to (0,0)
        Me.Top = 0
        Me.Left = 0

        'Set this form's backgroundimage with bitmap of bmp, that have been taken by graphic g
        Me.BackgroundImage = bmp
        Me.Show()

        Me.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Caller Form

```
Public Class FrmCaller
    Private Sub ButtonToPick_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonToPick.Click
        'Hide the caller form if don't need this form when you run your sniff or clip
        Me.Hide()
        FrmDesktopDisplay.ShowDialog()
        'To show again this form
        Me.Show()

        'Take the result from FrmDesktopDisplay, you can do it, because the form still active
        Dim myResultStts As Boolean = FrmDesktopDisplay.myResultStts
        Dim myResultValue As Integer = FrmDesktopDisplay.myResultValue

        'Here you close the FrmDesktopDisplay
        FrmDesktopDisplay.Close()
        FrmDesktopDisplay.Dispose()
        PictureBox1.Visible = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'Here you must have PictureBox1 in Your Form, and the form must be as parent container

Private Sub ButtonToPick_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonToPick.Click
    PictureBox1.Visible = False
    Me.Refresh()
    Dim g As Graphics
    Dim bmp As Bitmap
    bmp = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
    g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    Dim myFRect As Rectangle
    myFRect = Me.RectangleToScreen(Me.DisplayRectangle)
    g.CopyFromScreen(myFRect.Left, myFRect.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size)


    PictureBox1.Top = 0
    PictureBox1.Left = 0
    PictureBox1.Width = Me.Width
    PictureBox1.Height = Me.Height
    PictureBox1.Image = bmp
    PictureBox1.Visible = True
    PictureBox1.BringToFront()
    'Me.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    'Here you process before picture box be hidden again
    PictureBox1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I need it to basically freeze the desktop, as clicking somewhere to get the color could potentially interfere with something and change the color (like when you hover over a button for example). Hopefully my wording there is better.

Comment: OK, I understand it, so will you accept if your desktop temporarily to be covered by any form to display your desktop image?

Comment: I have make another sample to make desktop will freeze temporarily until you key in esc or finish your process, for example, when click any area on desktop screen

Comment: that works thanks (I had to change and add a few stuff but nothing hard)